# google analytics - Customer Report to show URLS that contain a specific word

Tags: google-analytics

On my site I have a ton of visitors to some pages where I show sentence examples. The urls in which the users visit are structured as such

Mobile Version

```
/m/sentence-examples/exec-exse/expulse/

/m/sentence-examples/benz-biff/bespeak/
```

Desktop Version

```
/sentence-examples/with/ineradicably

/sentence-examples/with/inheritor
```

I want to pull up a report that shows me how many times anyone visits any url that contains

```
/m/sentence-examples/
```

and

```
/sentence-examples/
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an "Advanced Segment" for "Page -> Contains -> 'sentence-examples'".

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033017?hl=en

If you need to look at more than 1 and/or a dynamic amount of "sentence-examples", you'll probably have to implement some custom tracking / custom variables / profile filtering.